# jQuery doesn't add or remove class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why doesn't my jQuery code add and later remove loading class?

```
$('#crop').click(function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault()
    $.post('frame.php?action=crop', dimensions, function (json) {
        $('body').addClass('loading')
        picture()
    }, 'json')
    $('body').removeClass('loading')
})
```

Chrome and Firebug consoles are empty, so there shouldn't be any errors.
jQuery version is 1.4.4

Comment: So what is happening?  Is it not getting added, or not getting removed?

Comment: Semicolons are a really good idea.

Comment: If there's no errors in the console, though, then the missing semicolons probably aren't the problem.

Comment: Approximate jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7tPCg/ - I'm guessing the problem is it getting removed then added, rather than the other way around as intended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What it does is remove and then later add the class.

You're adding the class in the callback to `$.post()`, which will happen long *after* the subsequent removal of the class. If you swap those lines (do the add after the `$.post()` call and the remove in the callback) then it'll be closer to what you want.

Comment: @DanielA.White sorry about the premature posting; it's fixed now.

Comment: Thanks man. This helped me a lot, I did not know that before.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mixed with the order...

```
$('#crop').click(function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault()
    $.post('frame.php?action=crop', dimensions, function (json) {
        $('body').addClass('loading') // here you should remove the loading!
        picture()
    }, 'json')
    $('body').removeClass('loading') // here you should add the loading!
})
```

It should be:

```
$('#crop').click(function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    $.post('frame.php?action=crop', dimensions, function (json) {
        $('body').removeClass('loading');
        picture();
    }, 'json');
    $('body').addClass('loading');
});
```

Note that while terminate your's lines with semi-colon(`;`) isn't mandatory, it's best practice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know it's good practice but I personally don't like the line ending noise.

Comment: @airmattress. It can save you trouble, and it's mandatory for minified versions. up to you... Good luck!

Comment: Only place I use semicolons is on StackOverflow. `:)`

Comment: @amnotiam. Weird, I'm using them on the end of my lines... `;-)` seriously, for non expert js programmers, semicolons should be mandatory!

Comment: Yeah, instead I'd say for absolute beginners they should be used. Anyone beyond that should be able to choose their style safely. There's really not that many places in one's code where their absence would cause trouble.

Comment: @airmattress if any answer helps you directly or indirectly, you should accept the best one.